# How to calculate elapsed time t(d) with given velocity over distance v(d)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm trying to calculate the time difference of a musical tempo change, e.g. going from 60bpm to 100bpm in 16 beats.

Symbols and units:

- t = time in $min$ (= minutes)
- d = distance in $b$ (= beats)
- v = velocity in $bpm$ or $b/min$ (= beats per minute)

Time starts at 0 beats $\left(t(0b) = 0min\right)$.

The example's velocity in relation to distance:

$$\forall d \in \left[0b, 16b\right], v(d) = 60bpm + 40bpm * \frac{d}{16 b}$$

In theory, every distance d (in this example!) must have exactly one point in time t and every point in time must have exactly one distance d. But does $t(d)$ actually exist?

Comment: How is t defined in terms of the other variables? Does $t = \frac{d}{v}$?

Comment: @Paul according to physical laws, $v=\frac{d}{t}$, so $t=\frac{d}{t}$ would work, if $v$ was constant. But it's not. A friend suggested involving acceleration, but that wouldn't work with different (e.g. exponential) functions of $v(d)$, right?

Comment: What is a beat?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I use it as a length unit here. Basically, you could change up the units without affecting the result: $1b = 1m$ (meter). $1bpm = 1\frac{m}{min} = \frac{1}{60}\frac{m}{s}$.

Comment: Are you assuming a uniform (i.e., linear) increase in tempo during the transition?

Comment: When drawing a graph of v(d), it appears linear (though v(t) probably grows exponentially). So, yes, let's assume v(d) increases linearly. @amd

Answer (score 0):

I did some reverse-engineer-trial-and-erroring and got kind of an answer, but I can't explain it and it only works if $v(d)$ is linear.

- $v_0 = 60bpm$ (velocity at transition start)
- $v_1 = 100bpm$ (velocity at transition end)
- $l = 16b$ (the transition goes on for 16 beats)

$$v(d) = v_0 + (v_1 - v_0) * \frac{d}{l}$$

$$c=\frac{d}{v(d)-v_0} = \frac{d}{(v_1-v_0)*\frac{d}{l}} = \frac{l}{v_1-v_0}$$

$$t(d)=ln((v(d))^c) - ln({v_0}^c)$$

Solving my example:
$c = \frac{16}{100 - 60} = 0.4$
$t(16) = ln({v_1}^{0.4}) - ln({v_0}^{0.4}) = 0.20433min \approx 12.26s$